# growing os size on hdd

Tags: disk-usage

Are all the obsolete packages deleted after an upgrade/update? I ask because my HD is growing with all these 300+MB updates. Should I be running a `make clean' after each upgrade/update?
Thanks for any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I generally run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Comment: Post that as an answer with a brief description of those options.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled, run :

```
sudo make clean
```

If you used `apt-get`, run :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```